# fullcalendar adding qtip with events.php

Tags: fullcalendar

I need to add a qtip but i dont get it to work.

I wanna use it for long description, 
This is wat i use, where and how must i put the eventrender?

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
        element.qtip({
            content: event.description


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
       editable: true,
       header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
       },

  timeFormat: 'HH(:mm)',
     events: 'events.php    ',
        });

     });


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put it in your script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
       var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
           editable: true,
           header: {
               left: 'prev,next today',
               center: 'title',
               right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
           },

           timeFormat: 'HH(:mm)',
           events: 'events.php',

           eventRender: function (event, element) {
               element.qtip({
                   content: event.description
               });
           }
       });
   });
```

I have an existing running example there if you want to see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/slyvain/fpuppLzy/

Comment: Hy Slyvain when i try this i see a blank calendar, no events?